# org.opencv.BuildConfig is defined multiple times

Tags: android, opencv, dex

I update an .aar dependency and in this new version was added an OpenCV dependency. And in the project I'm working has another dependency and it is used an OpenCV dependency too but with different version. In debug build is working fine but when I'm trying to run a release build, the follow error show for me:

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type org.opencv.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /[myPath]canoa/build/.transforms/bf16c92d6dcc96ca8411ea3aa706b978/transformed/jetified-canoa-sdk_2.3.0-runtime/dex/classes.dex, [myPath]/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/prodRelease/mergeExtDexProdRelease/classes5.dex","sources":[{"file":"[myProjectPath]canoa/build/.transforms/bf16c92d6dcc96ca8411ea3aa706b978/transformed/jetified-canoa-sdk_2.3.0-runtime/dex/classes.dex"}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Type org.opencv.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /myPathProject/build/.transforms/bf16c92d6dcc96ca8411ea3aa706b978/transformed/jetified-canoa-sdk_2.3.0-runtime/dex/classes.dex, [myPathProject]/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/prodRelease/mergeExtDexProdRelease/classes5.dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
```